# Why console says my keys are not unique?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

My console says that all keys are not unique, and that's why my removeItem function doesn't work. I'm trying to make a to-do list with React.js, and now I'm adding remove button. Can you help me? Here's the code:

```
var TodoItems = React.createClass({ //This is the removeItem function, that takes the key as a parameter and compares i.key to parameter.

  removeItem: function(key){
    var itemArray = this.props.entries;
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
      if (itemArray[i.key] === key) {
          itemArray.splice(i, 1);
          break;
      }
  },

  render: function() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    var _removeItem = this.removeItem;

    function createTasks(item) {
      return (
        <div>
          <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>
          <button onClick = {_removeItem(item.key)} className= "remove"> Remove </button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    var listItems = todoEntries.map(createTasks);

    return (
      <ul className="theList">
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    );

  }
});


var TodoList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },

  addItem: function(e) {
    var itemArray = this.state.items;

   //Here I create the key:

  itemArray.push(
   {
     text: this._inputElement.value,
     key: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
   }
 );

 this.setState({
   items: itemArray
 });

 this._inputElement.value = "";

 e.preventDefault();


 },

  render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="todoListMain">
          <div className="header">
            <form onSubmit = {this.addItem}>
              <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
                placeholder="enter task">
              </input>
              <button type="submit">add</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: When you pass a function into .map, you have access to 2 arguments, the current item your mapping in the array, and an 'index'. You can use this index as the key to your element, without having to manually generate one. For example: `function createTasks(item, index) {`

Comment: `i.key` -- `i` is a number like 3, 4 or 5. And you can't read property `i.key` of it, it's just not defined what is `key` of a Number. `i` stands for index, not item. Should be `itemArray[i].key`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within your `createTasks` function.

```
function createTasks(item) {
  return (
    <div>
      <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>
      <button onClick = {_removeItem(item.key)} className= "remove"> Remove </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You're return an array of `divs` to populate an unordered list. Firstly, you should be populating any `ul` element with `li`, and any content within that `li` element.

The reason reactjs is giving you can error is because you're adding your `key` to a child of the element you're returning instead of the root node, in this case a `div`.

Also, your removeItem function isn't working because it looks like it's being invoked when you're building each task, I've edited my answer to resolve this.

The following should work without issue:

```
function createTasks(item) {
  return (
      <li key={item.key}>
          {item.text}
          <button onClick = {this.removeItem.bind(this, item.key)} className= "remove"> Remove </button>
      </li>
  );
}
```

Edited: I misread a portion of the question, and have edited my answer.